# Question about the radius of convergence in the Lagrange Inversion Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analytic-functions, lagrange-inversion

Suppose that $f(x)$ has an inverse function $g(x)$. Suppose that both functions have a power series representations:
\begin{align}
f(x)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty f_k\frac{x^k}{k!} \text{ and } g(x)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty g_k\frac{x^k}{k!}
\end{align}
with $f_0=0$ and $f_1 \neq 0$.
Then, the Lagrange inversion theorem  say that we can coefficients of $f$ and $g$ as follows:
\begin{align}
g_1&=\frac{1}{f_1},\\
g_n&= \frac{1}{f_1^n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (-1)^k n^{(k)} B_{n-1,k}(\hat{f}_1,\ldots, \hat{f}_{n-k}), n \ge 2
\end{align}
where   $\hat{f}_k=\frac{f_{k+1}}{(k+1) f_1}$ and $n^{(k)}$ is rising factorial.

Questions: I have the following question about this result

1. Suppose that the representation of $f$ holds only for $|x|<r$ (i.e., has a finite radius of convergence). Does this the result still hold on $|x|<r$?
2. What can we say about the radius of convergence of $g$? Can it be found? Or do we have to do a root test on the new coefficients to find it?
3. How does this formula change if I have an expansion of $f$ around $x=a$ (i.e., $f(x)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty f_k\frac{(x-a)^k}{k!}$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about $f(x) = \log(1+x)$ and $g(x) = e^x - 1$.  The radii of convergence of their power series are really quite unrelated.

Comment: So, the theorem holds even if the power series of $f$ has a finite radius of convergence?

Comment: If $f$ has a finite radius of convergence, the inverse function will have a power series.  You just don't know what its radius of convergence is going to be without more details.

Comment: This is all easier if you have taken a course on complex variables.  Then it becomes a question about the domain of analyticity of the inverse of an analytic function.

Comment: Another really interesting example is the Lambert $W$ function, which is the inverse to $xe^x$.

Comment: Ok. Got it. I do know what the region of analyticity is.   So, in general, the only thing we really can do is apply a root test to the new series, right?

Comment: There are probably other tests in specific situations, but they will be just as difficult.

Comment: Ok. One more question. How does this formula change if the expansion of $f$ around $x=a$ and not $x=0$?

Comment: You can always shift the function by looking at $f(x+a)$, whose inverse will be $g(x) - a$.

Comment: Also, I co-authored a paper that dealt with these kinds of issues: http://faculty.missouri.edu/~stephen/preprints/t_pow_n.html Look at Chapter 4.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will take a look.

Comment: It is quite hard, so don't get too discouraged by it.